# Crash in QWebView

Tags: qt, crash, qwebview

My application contains a class which inherits QWebView. The problem is that I get a crash every time I try to type something in this view! Here's my code :

```
void QViewSupport::setupSupport(QWidget * widget)
{
    QUrl startURL = QUrl("http://www.google.fr");

    load(startURL);
}
```

So basically whenever I try to type something in the google search bar, it crashes at the first character...
Here's the output :

```
ASSERTION FAILED: ICU could not open a break iterator:    
U_MISSING_RESOURCE_ERROR (2)
U_SUCCESS(openStatus)
c:\work\build\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtwebkit\source\webcore\platform\text\TextBreakIteratorICU.cpp(45) : WebCore::setUpIterator
1   02426EF7
2   018F0F40
3   018F0CA0
4   018F0E1A
5   0207D7D3
6   0207CE91
7   014F1470
8   01CDBBF5
9   013EEEAC
10  013A45BE
11  01392CA7
12  013A4076
13  0134C062
14  0136166A
15  0144F19A
16  014562E3
17  014205E5
18  0141D9A6
19  017DCE6C
20  0134C82C
21  014EA80F
22  014F1525
23  013EEEAC
24  013A45BE
25  01392CA7
26  013A4076
27  0134C062
28  0136166A
29  017DCE25
30  014202C3
31  0100D627
First chance exception at 0x02426ef7 (Qt5WebKitd.dll) in myApp.exe : 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xbbadbeef.
Unhandled exception à 0x02426ef7 (Qt5WebKitd.dll) in myApp.exe : 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xbbadbe
```

Am I missing something? I searched the Internet and couldn't find something close to this problem. Thanks in advance if you have the solution!

**Edit** : As asked, here's the class :

```
class QViewSupport : public QWebView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QViewSupport(QWidget *parent);
    ~QViewSupport();

private:
    void setupSupport(QWidget *Form);

};
```

And in the .cpp file :

```
#include "qviewsupport.h"

QViewSupport::QViewSupport(QWidget *parent)
    : QWebView(parent)
{
     setupSupport(this);
}

void QViewSupport::setupSupport(QWidget * widget)
{
    QUrl startURL = QUrl("http://www.google.fr");

    load(startURL);
}

QViewSupport::~QViewSupport()
{

}
```

**Edit** : The call to this function is done in Setup.cpp (see below), and `pViewSupport` is a private member define in the `Setup` class : `QViewSupport* pViewSupport;`.

```
Setup::Setup(QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
}

void Setup::setupUi(QWidget * widget)
{
    // plenty of other things

    pViewSupport = new QViewSupport(this);

    // same
}
```

Comment: Something might be wrong with your class which inherits from `QWebView`. Post your derived class implementation so that we can check what went wrong.

Comment: I have modified it on your request

Comment: What's the purpose of the `QWidget` pointer that you pass to the setupSupport method? I don't see you using it.

Comment: I originally called it like that : `widget->setWindowTitle(...)` but since this is not relevant I removed it there. I tried with and without this `QWidget`, same result.

Comment: Could you post your main or the function where you create your webview object?

Comment: @nnb I did it but I don't think it's relevant here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem came from the ICU dlls from Qt, I just replaced them and it worked.